# Show user names on the login screen

Tags: display, greeter

Is it typical that others than first user name, are not shown on the login screen(greeter)? I'm using Loki. Right now i see name near the first account only, the two next just got it's icons. But when i try to click on the icons, they do not work. I must click on the right of them, so then login name and password input box appear. I would like to see names near icons like on the first account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is typical. That is the way the login screen is setup. I use the arrow keys to switch between accounts.

I'm currently making a list of small things like this that need tweaked to give Elementary OS more polish. It's just the way it is for now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You. So i resolved my problem by installing Webkit Greeter with command:

```
apt install lightdm-webkit-greeter
```

And inside /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf i have added "greeter-session=lightdm-webkit-greeter" in the section [Seat:*].
Then i installed LightDM-Webkit-MacOSX-Theme with new commits, and it looks very nice with names near every user :)